# send value from one select to another

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#the-selector div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a').click(function(){
           var countrySect = $('#the-selector div.jqTransformSelectWrapper span').text(); 

        });
    });
```

So as you noticed the var "countrySect" returns the value in the select input. the problem is i have another one similar to this one but with another class. I am trying to select value in the first one and set it to the second.. here is my full code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#the-selector div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a').click(function(){
           var countrySect = $('#the-selector div.jqTransformSelectWrapper span').text(); 
           $('.register-state div.jqTransformSelectWrapper span').val(countrySect);
           return true;
        });
    });
```

But nothing is happens... what em i doing wrong?

Comment: You do know you're setting the value of a span element, which has no value property ?

Comment: you need to use `.html` instead of `.val`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.html()`

```
$('.register-state div.jqTransformSelectWrapper span').html(countrySect);
```

because to set value inside span you need to use either `.text()` or `.html()`.